# slurm completes job without executing

Tags: slurm

I'm fairly new to slurm. I couldn't find my problem in any forum, so I guess either its very simple or very unnusual (or I don't know how to search).

The script I'm submitting is

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH -p all # partition (queue)
#SBATCH -N 1 # number of nodes
#SBATCH -n 1 # number of cores
#SBATCH -o ./slurm.%N.%j.out # STDOUT
#SBATCH -e ./slurm.%N.%j.err # STDERR
#SBATCH -t 300
#SBATCH --mem=5000
./kzsqrt 10.0
```

When I use

```
$ squeue -u rmelo
```

the queue is empty. If I try

```
$ show jobid -dd 157
```

the result is

```
JobId=157 Name=script_10.0.sh
UserId=rmelo(508) GroupId=rmelo(509)
Priority=4294901747 Account=(null) QOS=(null)
JobState=COMPLETED Reason=None Dependency=(null)
Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=1 ExitCode=0:1
DerivedExitCode=0:0
RunTime=00:00:00 TimeLimit=05:00:00 TimeMin=N/A
SubmitTime=2017-05-07T16:00:45 EligibleTime=2017-05-07T16:00:45
StartTime=2017-05-07T16:00:45 EndTime=2017-05-07T16:00:45
PreemptTime=None SuspendTime=None SecsPreSuspend=0
Partition=all AllocNode:Sid=headnode:20528
ReqNodeList=(null) ExcNodeList=(null)
NodeList=service1
BatchHost=service1
NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=24 CPUs/Task=1 ReqS:C:T=*:*:*
Nodes=service1 CPU_IDs=0-11 Mem=0
MinCPUsNode=1 MinMemoryNode=5000M MinTmpDiskNode=0
Features=(null) Gres=(null) Reservation=(null)
Shared=0 Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)
Command=/home/rmelo/modeloantigo/script_10.0.sh
WorkDir=/home/rmelo/modeloantigo
```

So my job is finishing instantly, without doing nothing. It doesn't even create the output file specified with #SBATCH -o. I've tried simple commands instead of the program i intend to run, like echo or sleep, with same result.

Any help or source to learn is appreciated.

Comment: Try to check the output files (.out and .err) in order to see what's happening.

Comment: Such a behaviour is often due to cluster misconfiguration (often usernames not properly synchronised) You should report it to your cluster administrator